# Populating textarea in a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
// Open modal window with links
$('.links').colorbox({speed:100, opacity:0.75, html:'<div id="links-colorbox"><h2>Download links</h2><textarea name="links"></textarea></div>'});

// Populate textarea with links
for(i in linkList) {
    $('#links-colorbox textarea').append('http://site.com/' + linkList[i][0] + '/' + linkList[i][1] + '\n');
}
```

The problem is the textarea in the modal window doesn't get populated, probably because it's inserted into the DOM on the fly with the modal window plugin I'm using.

Is there a way I can make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Your modal plugin will have an option to accept a callback function that gets called when its done loading the modal. At that stage, the textarea should be in the dom. Second, why are you calling append on the textarea? You want to append to the text inside the textarea.

Comment: Can you have a callback function in colorbox?  That might do it.

Comment: Indeed. I was going to ffer using `..</textarea></div>'}, onComplete: function(){ for(i in linkList) {
    $('#links-colorbox textarea').append('http://site.com/' + linkList[i][0] + '/' + linkList[i][1] + '\n');
}
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `oncomplete` callback:

```
$('.links').colorbox({
    speed:100,
    opacity:0.75,
    html:'<div id="links-colorbox"><h2>Download links</h2><textarea name="links"></textarea></div>',
    onComplete: function() {
        for(i in linkList) {
            $('#links-colorbox textarea').append('http://site.com/' + linkList[i][0] + '/' + linkList[i][1] + '\n');
        }
    }
});
```